# Google Maps Make Search Marker Open InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The map below has a built in search functionality that drops a pin when search is submitted.

The map also has a GeoJson layer that if clicked opens an InfoWindow.

At the moment the InfoWindow can only be opened when a user manually clicks on a polygon.

Is it possible to make it so that when a user searches for an address, say "Calgary Canada" when the pin drops it opens the info window automatically?

If there is no polygon under the marker it should not open anything.

```js
     // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
      // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
      // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
        
      function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 49.656963, lng: -112.506664},
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
          gestureHandling: 'greedy'
        });
          
          map.data.loadGeoJson('https://api.npoint.io/a5cec0395277a59090e7');

        // Color each letter gray. Change the color when the isColorful property
        // is set to true.
        map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
          var color = feature.getProperty('COLOR');
          return /** @type {!google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
            fillColor: color,
            strokeColor: 'black',
            strokeWeight: 2
          });
        });
          

        // a popup with the Health Region name and the score for Sense of Community Belonging
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    zIndex: 2
            });
        
        
         map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
                 
            map.data.revertStyle();
            map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {strokeWeight: 2, strokeColor: 'black', zIndex: 1});
            
            var CDNAME  = event.feature.getProperty('CDNAME');
            var COLOR   = event.feature.getProperty('COLOR');
            
            infoWindow.setPosition( event.latLng );
            infoWindow.setOptions( {
                pixelOffset: {width: 0, height: -3}
            });
        
            infoWindow.setContent(
                    "CDNAME: <b>" + CDNAME + "</b><br />" + 
                    "COLOR: <b>" + COLOR + "</b>"
            );  
            infoWindow.open(map);
            
         });
         
          
        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
              size: new google.maps.Size(50, 75),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 75)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            }));
              
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }
```

```css
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #description {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #infowindow-content .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }

      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }

      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }

      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }

      .pac-controls label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
```

```html
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
```

Desired final solution

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the `Infowindow` with the data from the `GeoJSON` Data Layer:

1. use the `loadGeoJson` callback function to capture the array of features from the GeoJson.

```
  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://api.npoint.io/a5cec0395277a59090e7', null, function(features) {
    jsonFeatures = features;
  });
```

2. When the `SearchBox` creates a marker, check if that marker is contained by one of the GeoJSON polygons (using the geometry.poly.containsLocation function).

```
  // Create a marker for each place.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: icon,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonFeatures.length; i++) {
    console.log(jsonFeatures[i].getGeometry().getType());
    if (jsonFeatures[i].getGeometry().getType() == "Polygon") {
      console.log("Polygon");
      var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: jsonFeatures[i].getGeometry().getArray()[0].getArray()
      });
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place.geometry.location, polygon)) {
        marker.feature = jsonFeatures[i];
        console.log("polygon[" + i + "] contains " + place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6));
        // openInfoWindow(place.geometry.location, jsonFeatures[i], marker);
        marker.addListener('click', function(evt) {
          openInfoWindow(place.geometry.location, this.feature, this);
        });
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
      }
    }
  }
```

3. Open the InfoWindow using the information from the containing polygon.

```
  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {

    map.data.revertStyle();
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      zIndex: 1
    });
    openInfoWindow(event.latLng, event.feature);
  });

  function openInfoWindow(latLng, feature, marker) {
    var CDNAME = feature.getProperty('CDNAME');
    var COLOR = feature.getProperty('COLOR');
    if (marker == null) {
      infoWindow.setPosition(latLng);
    } else {
      infoWindow.setOptions({
        pixelOffset: null
      });
    }
    infoWindow.setContent(
      "CDNAME: <b>" + CDNAME + "</b><br />" +
      "COLOR: <b>" + COLOR + "</b>"
    );
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gtn0m31k/2/)

[image: screenshot of result after seachbox returns result]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
var jsonFeatures;

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 49.656963,
      lng: -112.506664
    },
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    gestureHandling: 'greedy'
  });

  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://api.npoint.io/a5cec0395277a59090e7', null, function(features) {
    jsonFeatures = features;
  });


  // Color each letter gray. Change the color when the isColorful property
  // is set to true.
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var color = feature.getProperty('COLOR');
    return /** @type {!google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ ({
      fillColor: color,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
  });


  // a popup with the Health Region name and the score for Sense of Community Belonging
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    zIndex: 2
  });


  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {

    map.data.revertStyle();
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      zIndex: 1
    });
    openInfoWindow(event.latLng, event.feature);


  });

  function openInfoWindow(latLng, feature, marker) {
    var CDNAME = feature.getProperty('CDNAME');
    var COLOR = feature.getProperty('COLOR');
    if (marker == null) {
      infoWindow.setPosition(latLng);
    } else {
      infoWindow.setOptions({
        pixelOffset: null
      });
    }

    infoWindow.setContent(
      "CDNAME: <b>" + CDNAME + "</b><br />" +
      "COLOR: <b>" + COLOR + "</b>"
    );
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  }

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = {
        url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
      });
      markers.push(marker);
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonFeatures.length; i++) {
        console.log(jsonFeatures[i].getGeometry().getType());
        if (jsonFeatures[i].getGeometry().getType() == "Polygon") {
          console.log("Polygon");
          var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: jsonFeatures[i].getGeometry().getArray()[0].getArray()
          });
          if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place.geometry.location, polygon)) {
            marker.feature = jsonFeatures[i];
            console.log("polygon[" + i + "] contains " + place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6));
            // openInfoWindow(place.geometry.location, jsonFeatures[i], marker);
            marker.addListener('click', function(evt) {
              openInfoWindow(place.geometry.location, this.feature, this);
            });
            google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
          }
        }
      }
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```